# Why apex:pageblocktable refresh automatically when i remove a row with jquery?

Tags: jquery, row, apex-code, visualforce

My issue is this : I have a simple pageblocktable with some records, when I remove one specific row from the table ... this work well for a moment, then my page is automatically reloaded with the complete pageblocktable and all the rows.

My wish is not delete a record, but to make impossible the view of a row.

This is the code of my controller:

```
public List<E2C_Email__c> emailsmod;


public List<E2C_Email__c> getEmailsmod (){

String id='500T0000004QpWr';

this.emailsmod=[Select id,subject__c,FromName__c,Read__c,CreatedDate,CcAddress__c from E2C_Email__c where Case__c=:id ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC];

return this.emailsmod;

}
```

And this is the code of my script (in the page) :

```
 <script type="text/javascript">            
     $j = jQuery.noConflict();                   
     function hiderows(){    
        var prova= $j('#subject'+ 'a0TT0000003BMmGMAW').parent();     
        var prova2=$j('#subject'+ 'a0TT0000003BMmGMAW').closest("tr");          
        prova2.remove();     
     }                   
</script>
```

and this is the page

```
<apex:form >

    <apex:outputpanel >

        <apex:commandbutton value="prova" onclick="hiderows()" />

    </apex:outputpanel>



</apex:form>
<apex:outputpanel layout="block" style="overflow:auto;height:200px">
    <apex:pageBlock id="pb" mode="maindetail">
        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!Emailsmod}" var="e" columns="5"
            cellspacing="5" onRowClick="show(this)">

            <apex:column headerValue="From" width="22%">
                <span id="from{!e.id}"> {!e.FromName__c} </span>
            </apex:column>
            <apex:column headerValue="Subject">
                <span id="subject{!e.id}"> {!e.Subject__c} </span>
            </apex:column>
            <apex:column headerValue="Date" width="7%">
                <span id="date{!e.id}"> <apex:outputText value="{0,date,dd/MM/yy hh:mm}">
                    <apex:param value="{!e.CreatedDate}" />
                </apex:outputText> </span>
            </apex:column>

        </apex:pageBlockTable>
    </apex:pageBlock>


</apex:outputpanel>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just try this trick out - add return false after executing your JavaScript function:

```
<apex:commandButton value="prova" onclick="hiderows(); return false;"/>
```

Other way to avoid page reload is to add a dummy reRender tag:

```
<apex:commandButton value="prova" onclick="hiderows()" reRender="none" />
```

You must to re-render "something" to avoid the page reload. Otherwise the command button will reload the whole page. In our case we will re-renden "nothing".